# Is it possible to style some part of text in innerHtmlin JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, innerhtml

I want to style some part of my paragraph before appending it to html page. I have tried some methods but they are not working. see commented syntax. I want to style the word `Description` What is the proper way of doing this? Thank You.

```js
const detailsDiv = document.getElementById("details");
var articleDecs = document.createElement("p");
articleDecs.setAttribute("class", "productDesc");
var str = "Description:  ";
//var str2 = str.bold();
//var str3 = "<b>Description:  </b>" ;
articleDecs.innerText = "Description: " +catalogArray[pos].desc;

//articleDecs.innerText = str2  +catalogArray[pos].desc;
//articleDecs.innerText = str3 "+catalogArray[pos].desc;
console.log(articleDecs);
detailsDiv.appendChild(articleDecs);
```

```html
<div id="details"></div>
```

Comment: I edited your snippet and fixed the console errors `var str3 = "<b>Description:  </b" > ;` is invalid

Comment: What do you want to style ? the created p tag ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you concatenate correctly and use innerHTML it works

```js
const catalogArray = [{
  desc: "Desc 1"
}]

let pos = 0

const detailsDiv = document.getElementById("details");
var articleDecs = document.createElement("p");
articleDecs.setAttribute("class", "productDesc");
var str1 = "Description:  ".bold();
articleDecs.innerHTML = str1 + catalogArray[pos].desc;
console.log(articleDecs);
detailsDiv.appendChild(articleDecs);
```

```html
<div id="details"></div>
```

But why not use CSS instead of .bold()

```js
const catalogArray = [{
  desc: "Desc 1"
}]

let pos = 0

const detailsDiv = document.getElementById("details");
var articleDecs = document.createElement("span");
articleDecs.setAttribute("class", "productDesc");
articleDecs.innerText = "Description:  ";
detailsDiv.appendChild(articleDecs);
detailsDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(catalogArray[pos].desc));
```

```css
.productDesc { font-weight:bold }
```

```html
<div id="details"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use js for styling, this would be it:

```js
var catalogArray = [{
    desc: "Desc 1"
}]

var pos = 0;

const detailsDiv = document.getElementById("details");
var articleDecs = document.createElement("p");
articleDecs.setAttribute("class", "productDesc");
articleDecs.innerHTML = "Description:" + catalogArray[pos].desc;
articleDecs.style.fontWeight = "bold";
detailsDiv.appendChild(articleDecs);
```

```html
<div id="details"></div>
```